# Finding Error in manifest.json file

Tags: manifest

Here is my code :

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "45.0.2454.93",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "icons":{
    "48": "a3.jpg",
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "a3.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  }
}
```

it shows "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 8, column: 4, Trailing comma not allowed."

Comment: Here is a handy little tool to validate JSON - http://jsonlint.com/. This tool complains about the comma character inside key 48 of the "icons" object.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: You should pass your json through that tool, see what the errors are and then fix them

Answer (score 0):

See when you have to provide multiple arguments in JSON you have to provide  a comma at the end of the parameter. But in the last part of JSON you should not provide a comma. That's called the trailing comma.

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "45.0.2454.93",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "icons":{
    "48": "a3.jpg"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "a3.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

This will fix the issue, Hope this helps!!